# how to swap the first 2 elements of an array using a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
function swap(arr){
var finalarr = [];
var tempArr = arr;

for(i=0; i<1; i++){
    arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = tempArr[i + 1];
}
return arr;
}
```

`swap([1,2,3,4])` was supposed to be => `[2,1,3,4]`,
but instead it is outputting => `[1,1,3,4]`.

Can you modify this array to swap the first 2 elements in the arrray?

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the second element of the array before saving its value, so the value at `[1]` gets lost forever using your method.

You can either save that value first, and then assign it to `arr[0]`

```js
function swap(arr) {
  const item1 = arr[1];
  arr[1] = arr[0];
  arr[0] = item1;
  return arr;
}
console.log(swap([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Or, more preferably, use destructuring to avoid the need for a separate variable:

```js
const swap = ([item0, item1, ...rest]) => [item1, item0, ...rest];
console.log(swap([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Or, if you have to mutate the existing array:

```js
function swap(arr) {
  [arr[0], arr[1]] = [arr[1], arr[0]];
  return arr;
}
console.log(swap([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Comment: https://jsbench.me/unl7qqqdai/1
1er is the more fast

Answer (score 0):

`tempArr` and `arr` are references to the same object (you can learn more [here](https://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/arrays/value-vs-reference.php)).

In your case you don't need to use a second array, you just need to store a temp value, so you can do for instance :

```
var temp = arr[i + 1]
arr[i + 1] = arr[i]
arr[i] = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a temporary variable, not array and not a loop to do this

```
var temp = arr[0];
arr[0] = arr[1];
arr[1] = temp;
```